# Bone heat weighting failed, But it's a low Poly character that is made with one object

Tags: rigging, armature, error

So, I modeled a low poly character with one cube. And I made the armature, and did ctrl + p --> with autometic weights, but it just  told me the error of Bone Heat Weighting Failed. I've searched for these kind of problems and every single thing was connected with high poly models...

Also, I'm an Newbie, so it will be nice to have specific instructions. :D Thanks you

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w74nb1Tfs26XYuPDtrtAQPXaXhoErehX/view?usp=sharing
This is the blend file of mine

Please help me, this is my first try of rigging, and I'm stuck...

Comment: hello, it looks like you have overlapping vertices, inner faces, floating edges, etc, you could try to fix it or redo your object, also apply the scales of both the object and the armature

Comment: There's also the problem you have bones for upper/lower body, upper/lower arm and upper/lower leg, but there are no vertices, no geometry for knees, elbows etc., nothing where the armature could bend the mesh. I mean, you've made high resolution parts for example on top and bottom of the arm, but the front and back faces go straight through from shoulder to wrist.